# Modify an internal href link for only narrower screens

Tags: html, css, anchor, responsive

I have an 'overview' html page with lots of product images - each image links to a page that may have 3 or 4 products, eg, src="gadgets-1.html"

On desktop, on the destination page the user can see most products or can easily scroll down if needed.

But on narrow screen where the css MQs convert all columns to 100% width, the last items are not necessarily in view and the user must intuit that it's necessary to swipe down the page, so I want the linking image to link directly to the relevant item on the destination page.

I've established anchor links which work well, eg, src="gadgets-1.html#red-thing" but I don't want the '#red-thing' to be active on wider screens.

To resume, I want the link to be gadgets-1.html on wider screen and
gadgets-1.html#red-thing on narrow screen.

I don't see how this can (or should) be done with css. Should js or php be used? If so, how?

Comment: Are you building your own css or using a framework? If it's the former, look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Thanks, but I know what media queries are. I could use a system of MQs with max and min widths and display:none, but it would be necessary to duplicate the 'a' elements and would be v clunky.

Comment: If you are making your own css you could have your single <a> element that behaves one way on a smaller screen and another way on a bigger screen. Nothing clunky about that. Is there a specific solution you are looking for?

Comment: How would I use css to modify the url of a single link?

Comment: afaik you cannot use css to modify attributes of html elements. You can use javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A flexible solution would be to use Javascript with a specific data- attribute for storing the different anchor names.

HTML:

```
<a class="targetLink" href="/link1" data-anchor="anchor-name1">Target link</a>
<a class="targetLink" href="/link2" data-anchor="anchor-name2">Target link</a>
```

To execute the code cross-browser on DOM ready and window resize, jQuery would be useful. 
Check [CodePen here](https://codepen.io/frenx/pen/qMqeNP)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $target = $(".targetLink");
    var $window = $(window);
    var breakpoint = 640;
    var linkSmall = false;

    function checkWidth() {
        if ($window.width() <= breakpoint) {
            // appends anchors to links
            if(!linkSmall){
                $target.each(function(index) {
                   var href2 = $(this).attr("href") + "#" + $(this).attr("data-anchor");
                   $(this).attr("href", href2 );
                });
                linkSmall = true;
            }
        }else{
            // removes anchors to links
            if(linkSmall){
                $target.each(function(index) {
                   var href1 = $(this).attr("href");
                   var a = href1.indexOf('#');
                   var href2 = href1.substring(0, a != -1 ? a : href1.length);
                   $(this).attr("href", href2 );
                });
                linkSmall = false;
            }
        }
    }
    checkWidth(); // on document ready
    $(window).resize(checkWidth); // on window resize
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly, easy to implement. I doubt anyone will need window resize but it's handy to have. The pages already used jQuery, so no problem - but would the above code not function without it?

Comment: No, it works only with jQuery. Without it you need a lot of code to manage the Dom-ready event cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of solutions I can think off of the top of my head. I don't usually like using javascript to modify the DOM based on screenwidth but it is an acceptable solution if you are so inclined.

OR you can do something simple like this:

```
<div class="links">
    <a class="mobileLink" href="gadgets-1.html#red-thing">gadgets-1</a>
    <a class="desktopLink" href="gadgets-1.html">gadgets-1</a>
</div>
```

with some css to hide the right link based on screen width

```
.mobileLink{
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .mobileLink{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .desktopLink{
        display: none;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you don't want to repeat anchor elements(as per the other threads), you won't be able to do it with css so you'll have to use js.

```
if(window.innerwidth < 911){
document.getElementsByClassName("class")[0].setAttribute("href", "url_for_small_screen_devices);
}else{
document.getElementsByClassName("class")[0].setAttribute("href", "url_for_normal_desktop_and_bigger_devices");
}
```

you can use a loop to repeat the same process for all anchors with using proper selectors.